# How to feed time data to h2o?

Tags: r, h2o

I'd like to know, how to add time data to h2o using as.h2o()?
I'm using a dataframe, which features minute records. R studio's function to form such a data type is as.POSIXct (or as.POSIXlt), which is not supported by h2o:

```
Provided column type POSIXct is unknown.  Cannot proceed with parse due to invalid argument.
```

The only other time function I've ran into is as.Date, which is not good, since it drops pretty much everything apart from the date. The official [FAQ](http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-docs/faq/data.html) to h2o mentions its time FORMAT requirements, but not the method to feed the data. I tried to import the data in that format, but it lists as CHR string type. I've also tried the chron package, but that data is imported as Chron objects to the h2o cluster. Not sure if h2o recognizes any of these as time data.

Comment: May be [here](https://rpubs.com/phamdinhkhanh/390053) ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [h2o.as_date(x, format, ...)](http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-r/docs/reference/h2o.as_date.html). `format` will specify the date-time pattern.

For example:

```
hdf <- h2o.importFile("https://s3.amazonaws.com/h2o-public-test-data/smalldata/jira/v-11-eurodate.csv")
h2o.as_date(hdf$ds5, "%d.%m.%y %H:%M")
```

Comment: I've tried, but h2o.str() lists it as CHR string, and when I'd like to train the model, I get the following error message, like before:

`Warning message:
In .h2o.processResponseWarnings(res) :
  Dropping bad and constant columns: [M1Date_Time].`

Constant is like:
2021-02-10 08:15:00
2021-02-10 08:14:00
2021-02-10 08:13:00
etc, since these are values of different minute candles on a stock chart.